# How to get the DOM elements of the active page in google app script from add-on

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently developing a google calendar add on . And I need to access the DOM of the current active page from the add On 
I need to know how to get the DOM element in app script for google add on

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the DOM of the active page, in your case the calendar? If that is your intention, you can achieve it by using      var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r").getContentText();
    Let me know if it was this what you were looking for. :)

Comment: Yes I already used this method but I didn’t got what I expected . Actually wat I am trying to do is . When I open a new event and add the meeting title and before saving it if I open the add on in the calendar the title of the event should be synced in the add on . I didn’t find any particular event in the calendar API where I can retrieve the event details before saving it. So I am trying to get the event title from the DOM . I didn’t got the event title from the UrlfetchApp function

Comment: Hi! I don't believe you can achieve this with Calendar's API for Apps Script. Unfortunately I also believe there is no possible way of getting the DOM with Apps Script. The closest you could possibly get is to [get a change in the Calendar's event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_calendar_events) such as an Edit, Addition or Deletion. You could also try to get the input tags by using this Javascript functionality `var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");`. Let me know if any of these two ways worked for you and if you need anything else.

Comment: If I use the calendar events I need to press save in order to get changes in the event. I need to get the changes in the event before saving . And also I tried to get the input tags using getElementsByTagName but for that I need to get the document i.e., the DOM of the active page otherwise ‘document is undefined’ error will be thrown . Kindly suggest a way to achieve my functionality

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Unfortunately, at the day of this answer there is no functionality in Apps Script to get the DOM of any site.

## Workaround

Try using a chrome addon as these might let you get the DOM of sites. [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) you can find out more about chrome add ons.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)